# c++ forward implementation

Tags: c++, c++14, reference

this is my implementation of std::forward

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr decltype(auto) forward(U && u) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T &&>(u);
}
```

compared to the standards

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T && forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type & __t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T &&>(__t);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T && forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type && __t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T &&>(__t);
}
```

the standard uses the *remove_reference* to ensure usage of:

```
forward<T>(value)
```

which then requires them to overload each rvalue / lvalue instance of forward. Whereas I am using a second template parameter to ensure the correct usage, which allows me not need an overload.

can anyone point out any downfalls in my implementation?

**Note**: decltype(auto) can be replaced with T && for the same results.

Comment: You should read [n2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) by Howard Hinnant.

Comment: You should ask somebody on the standard's committee. Also I bet they already have a million unit tests around the standard; why don't you find those and see if your version works for all those tests?

Answer (score 1):

Your version is less type-safe than the normal implementation.

`std::forward()` constrains the argument's value (after dereferencing) to be of the same type as the return type.

Your implementation can perform any type conversion supported by `static_cast`.  That allows this erroneous code to compile:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

int main()
{
    forward<Derived>(Base{});
}
```

If `std::forward()` is used instead, we get an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘forward<Derived>(Base)’
   14 |     std::forward<Derived>(Base{});
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

We can fix the function to correctly reject the problem code.  With C++20, we'd do that by adding a `requires` clause to constrain `U`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
requires (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<U> || !std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>)
    && std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_reference_t<U>*,
                             std::remove_reference_t<T>*>
constexpr decltype(auto) forward(U && u) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T &&>(u);
}
```

I don't think the `decltype(auto)` adds clarity, so I would actually write

```
constexpr T&& forward(U&& u) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(u);
}
```

Since the question tags say we're constrained to C++14, we'd need to reformulate the constraint as a `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_lvalue_reference<U>::value
                  || !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
                 && std::is_convertible<std::remove_reference_t<U>*,
                                        std::remove_reference_t<T>*>::value,
                 T&&>
forward(U&& u) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(u);
}
```

Comment: Well, the `std::forward`-replacement with two template-arguments you tried to fix up is now overly restrictive. `struct { operator int&(){ return data; } int data; } x; (void)std::forward<int&>(x);` would no longer work. Yes, the example is contrived, but that's not the point.